# Script to disable RDP

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to disable RDP using powershell.

I've tried the following code, but the values on the machine name I'm listing aren't changing.

```
$file = Get-Content c:\PSscripts\regchange\computers.txt
foreach ($computername in $file){
    $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address = '$computername'" | Select-Object StatusCode
    If ($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0){
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername )
        $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server" ,$true)
        $regKey.SetValue("fDenyTSConnections","1",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::dword)
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$computername unreachable"
    }
}
```

I suspect there's something wrong with the way I entered the registry path name. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know its not added?

Comment: I have access to the target machine. I'm just testing for mass deployment.

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as admin? System wide changes, Windows requires admin privs to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue must be either permissions (which I assume you have as there are no obvious error messages), refreshing issue  or in `Get-Content` and the structure of your file.

In order for `Get-Content` to work in this manner, each computer on a separate line. e.g.:

```
MyComputer1
MyComputer2
```

Another troubleshooting step is to try adding in `Write-Host $computername` entries to verify that you are looping through properly.:

```
$file = Get-Content c:\PSscripts\regchange\computers.txt
foreach ($computername in $file){
     $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address = '$computername'" | Select-Object StatusCode
     If ($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0){
         Write-Host "$computername set"
     }
    else {
        Write-Host "$computername unreachable"
    }
}
```

You can also confirm by adding in a `$regKey.GetValue` after setting:

```
$file = Get-Content c:\PSscripts\regchange\computers.txt
foreach ($computername in $file){
    $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address = '$computername'" | Select-Object StatusCode
    If ($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0){
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername )
        $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server" ,$true)
        $regKey.SetValue("fDenyTSConnections","1",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::dword)

        Write-Host "$computername set to: $($regKey.GetValue("fDenyTSConnections"))"

    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$computername unreachable"
    }
}
```

Manually setting `$computername = "MyComputer"` and running the code, I can confirm that the code for setting the registry works... I can also confirm that remotely killing your RDP access to your remote virtual workstation also works.. and... is as terrible as it sounds ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If PSRemoting is enabled, try something like this …
(This needs to be executed in a PowerShell elevated admin session.)

```
Get-Content -Path 'c:\PSscripts\regchange\computers.txt' | 
ForEach{
    If (Test-Connection -$PSItem -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        $paramblock = @{
            Path = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server'
            Name = 'fDenyTSConnections'
            Value = '1'
        }

        Invoke-Command –Computername $PSItem –ScriptBlock {Set-ItemProperty @paramblock}
    }
    Else
    {Write-Warning -Message "Either the host $PSItem is offline or not reachable."}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for deleting your latest answer. It's nice to help people who are lost, but we get such a volume of vampire questions here, we have to draw the line somewhere!